# Update Modified field in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, office365, csom

Is there any way to update the Modified field in Office 365? I have checked both CSOM and Batch update methods. But it's failed. Could anybody help me to update this field.

Answer (score 1):

Before attempting to set `Modified`, `Created`, `Editor`, and `Author` fields for a list item you need to disable a couple of properties on the List, specifically `EnableVersioning` and for good measure `ForceCheckout`.

SharePoint Online prerequisite is the SharePointOnline CSOM:

[.NET client API reference for SharePoint Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193041.aspx)

[Nuget - Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/)

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,password);
    var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var item = list.GetItemById(itemID);
    var user = context.Web.EnsureUser(accountName);
    context.Load(user);
    context.Load(list);
    context.Load(item);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    // If the properties are enabled on the list then disable them
    bool updateList = list.ForceCheckout || list.EnableVersioning;
    if (list.ForceCheckout) list.ForceCheckout = false;
    if (list.EnableVersioning) list.EnableVersioning = false;
    if (updateList)
    {
        list.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }

    // Now set the fields that are normally locked
    item["Modified"] = DateTime.Now;
    item["Created"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
    item["Author"] = user.Id;
    item["Editor"] = user.Id;

    item.Update();
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint CSOM API does not support system update ([SystemUpdate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate(v=office.15).aspx) counterpart from SSOM API)  but you could manipulate system fields like `Modified By` and `Modified` fields *directly* as demonstrated below.

> Prerequisites:  [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

```
using (var ctx = GetContext(webUri, userName, password))
{
    //get List Item
    var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
    //Retrieve User
    var user = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(accountName);
    ctx.Load(user);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    //Update system fields
    item["Modified"] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);
    item["Created"] = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    item["Editor"] = user.Id;
    item["Author"] = user.Id;
    item.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

where

```
public static ClientContext GetContext(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
    return new ClientContext(webUri) { Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword) };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint CSOM API now support system update using UpdateOverwriteVersion method. This way you can modify Modified, Created, Author and Editor properties without changing the item Version. For example:

```
        $file = Get-PnPFile -Url $FileUrl -AsListItem 
        ##update file properties 
        $item["Modified"] = $FileModifiedDate
        $item["Created"] = $FileCreatedDate 
        $item["Author"] = $FileCreatedByDest.ID 
        $item["Editor"] = $FileModifiedByDest.ID 
        $fileTest2.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
        Invoke-PnPQuery
```

That should do the trick.